# Where is javascript variable 'Spring' defined in spring webflow?

Tags: spring, maven-2, maven-3, spring-webflow

I am using spring webflow, my page got the following error:

```
Spring is not defined
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring....entId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));
```

I am wondering where is javascript variable `Spring` defined in spring framework. I am using maven, so what dependency should I add in?

Answer (score 1):

**Base Maven Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This will include this transitive dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Which contains the JavaScript resources:

**Resource:**

`META-INF/web-resources/spring/Spring.js`

Which you can serve if you configure Spring MVC as specified [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch12s02.html):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping  = "/resources/**"
               location = "/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />
```

> Note that the full resource URL
>   depends on how your `DispatcherServlet`
>   is mapped. In the mvc-booking sample
>   we've chosen to map it with the
>   default servlet mapping '/':

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> That means **the full URL to load
>   `Spring.js` is
>   `/myapp/resources/spring/Spring.js`**. If
>   your `DispatcherServlet` was instead
>   mapped to `/main/*` then the full URL
>   would be
>   `/myapp/main/resources/spring/Spring.js`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply,but how to import that js file? I remember I did not explicitly import it before. And I got no error. But I changed something and then it doesn't work.

Comment: @tom see this part of the reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch12s02.html

Comment: I am using spring3.0.4 and I added the following two lines:<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" />
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>,but not working.

Comment: @Tom I've changed my answer, the documentation and maven artifact version did not fit together.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate for your patience,I add all the configuration as your answer,and import spring.js explicitly like this:<script src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script> , now the error is :Spring.ValidateAllDecoration is not a constructor
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring....entId:'proceed', event:'onclick'})); And I found the example of webflow:swf-booking-mvc is not import any js explicitly.

Comment: @Tom sorry, I'd say that's a new question (and one I can't help with). I'd say that example uses an API that has been changed in the meantime, but I wouldn't know (I use Spring a lot, but have never used webflow)

Comment: Oh,thanks.  Now I got another error when I add artifactId:org.springframework.js. The erro is :Missing artifact org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0:compile

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue in Spring Roo and it turned out the problem was associated with the references to the dojo and spring scripts in the load-scripts.tagx file. The syntax should be as follows:

```
  <script src="${dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
  <script src="${spring_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- /required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
  <script src="${spring_dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

If you reformat to put the comments above the lines, then the spring.js is never included at runtime and so that's why you see 'Spring.addDecoration is undefined'.

At this point, I'm not sure why the tagx is so picky about this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved. First of all, must add configuration as Sean said.Then import the following js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"></script>
```

I did't use tiles in my webflow, the example of webflow using tiles and import that three js files in standard.jsp, that why I should import js files explicitly in every jsp file.